Descargar archivo de Facebook de la app de whatsapp de meta developers
estoy realizando una integración con la app de Whatsapp de meta developers de Facebook.
Estoy realizando pruebas y al momento de enviar un mensaje al numero de whatsapp de la app me trae el id con el que yo puedo descargar ese archivo, al momento de hacerlo por la aplicación Postman me trae el archivo correctamente, pero luego al momento de querer replicarlo en php ya que así funciona el sitio web no me descarga el archivo correctamente como si estuviera dañado, lo estoy realizando con cURL y así tengo el código:
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Bogota');
header("Cache-control: no-cache");

// Tu token de acceso
$token = 'Token proporcionado por Faceboock';

// ID del archivo subido (id_documento)
$id_documento = 'id del documento';

// URL para obtener la información del archivo
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/$id_documento";

// Configurar los encabezados de la solicitud
$headers = [
    "Authorization: Bearer $token",
    "Content-Type: application/json"
];

// Inicializar cURL para obtener la URL de descarga y tipo MIME
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// Ejecutar la solicitud
$respuesta = curl_exec($curl);

// Verificar si hay errores
if ($respuesta === false) {
    $error = curl_error($curl);
    echo "Error: $error";
    die("ERROR AL ENVIAR LA URL");
}

// Cerrar cURL inicial
curl_close($curl);

$data = json_decode($respuesta, true);

if ($data != '' && $data != NULL) {
    $url_descarga = $data['url'];
    $tipo_mime = $data['mime_type'];

    // Mapa MIME a extensión
    $mime_map = [
        'application/pdf' => 'pdf',
        'image/jpg' => 'jpg',
        'image/jpeg' => 'jpeg',
        'image/png' => 'png',
        'video/mp4' => 'mp4',
    ];

    $extension = isset($mime_map[$tipo_mime]) ? $mime_map[$tipo_mime] : 'bin';

    // Configurar los encabezados de la solicitud
    $headers = [
        "Authorization: Bearer $token"
    ];

    // Inicializar cURL para descargar el archivo
    $curl_archivo = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl_archivo, CURLOPT_URL, $url_descarga);
    curl_setopt($curl_archivo, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); // Usar el mismo header con el token
    curl_setopt($curl_archivo, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl_archivo, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl_archivo, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($curl_archivo, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // Desactivar verificación SSL si es necesario
    curl_setopt($curl_archivo, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);

    // Ejecutar la solicitud de descarga
    $datos_archivo = curl_exec($curl_archivo);

    // Verificar si hay errores en la descarga
    if ($datos_archivo === false) {
        $error = curl_error($curl_archivo);
        die("Error de descarga: $error");
    }

    // Obtener el código de respuesta HTTP
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($curl_archivo, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    // Verificar si la descarga fue exitosa (código 200)
    if ($httpCode !== 200) {
        die('Error: No se pudo descargar el archivo. HTTP Code: ' . $httpCode);
    }

    // Cerrar cURL de descarga
    curl_close($curl_archivo);
    
    // Guardar el archivo en el servidor con la extensión dinámica
    $archivo = "archivo_descargado.$extension";

    // Configurar las cabeceras HTTP para la descarga
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Type: $tipo_mime");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$archivo");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate");
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Content-Length: " . strlen($datos_archivo));

    // Enviar el contenido del archivo
    echo $datos_archivo;
}
?>

Cuando descarga el archivo me arroja un error que dice:
"Error
No se pudo cargar el documento PDF."
Pero el archivo si tiene el peso correcto, y también al momento de imprimir la respuesta del cURL me arroja lo siguiente:

Tengo el navegador actualizado y todo y sigue sin funcionar.
Sinceramente llevo un año programando y soy nuevo en esto de cURL y no entiendo el por que me falla.

porque mandas esto: "Content-Type: application/json" en el header cuando no hay nada de eso en el get???

@gbianchi Asi es como postman me responde con un json debido a esto siempre lo parametrizo, también lo hago por costumbre, aunque esa primera sección no es la que me causa error, ya que solo trae datos del documento en especifico. me devuelve algo como lo siguiente:
 {     "url": "url que consumo despues",     "mime_type": "image/jpeg",     "sha256": "f922b49764aa3e874a1",     "file_size": 97145,     "id": "0099",     "messaging_product": "whatsapp"  }

Este es uno de esos casos en que se necesita un ejemplo minimo verificable para poder ayudar hay tantas cosas que pueden estar afectando que sin poder reproducir exactamente el error y hacer un debug paso a paso, no sepodra dar con el problema ... comensando con verificar si se obtiene la url y el mime correcto tanto en postman como por curl ...

@FranciscoIALover, Hola perdón responder tan tarde, entiendo para el código que proporcione se necesita lo siguiente que es el id del documento y un token que en este caso dura 24 horas.
id documento: 7992406594112676
Token : EAAFgO74JtfABO5e1hBtZC4MvbmjUknlza1vFzqDbGSZBF8IGc3JLKZBO37ZBhZA84iKLvnJyQRAAIa3qWeHjMU1bHzAcpn5UZAAdw5eQASqOGOH28fG4uS6clMOZB0NXGSPWPmhzUbZBdZABNsHMkDVfjslU6UvYVQuVqoFCIhuy1Fn6sS3zBVS05lrOSRxKMzDm2YL4ygzCofyjGecsZD
Para mi código solo es parametrizar ambas cosas y ejecutarlo.

En el caso de postman lo que hago es en la url pongo lo siguiente:
-https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/7992406594112676
Con el metodo GET, En Authorization selecciono Bearer Token  Y coloco el proporcionado, y en Headers pongo:
-Content-Type: application/json
-Accept: application/json
y al momento de darle SEND me responde con los datos correctos.

responde lo siguiente:
{     "url": "https://lookaside.fbsbx.com/whatsapp_business/attachments/?mid=7992406594112676&ext=1719927368&hash=ATuOHH7UKw4KIRTjCOlLGtXl-ercG62m8XkYezADxaNieQ",     "mime_type": "image/jpeg",     "sha256": "d48901d167c8ed50026d0d8bc5ae222865894a79102c04d0c3080cb8219c5430",     "file_size": 222204,     "id": "7992406594112676",     "messaging_product": "whatsapp" }
Y en una nuevo pestaña de postman parametrizo el bearer token y en la url el que me respondió postman y me devuelve la imagen, el problema creo que esta en mi código.

intentaste con curl_setopt($curl_archivo, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

@FranciscoIALover.
Si señor, lo tengo parametrizado incluso en el código que subí.
Ya lo he intentado varias veces y no me funciona.

no entiendo ???
